# mysql use WHERE and LIKE with diffrent columns

Tags: mysql

I can't find an answer for such a situation:

I have a table:

```
id, name, state
```

I want to search NAME column but only for records WHERE state=1
so something like this (of course it's wrong but the idea)

```
SELECT id, name FROM table_name WHERE state=1 AND WHERE name LIKE '%ss%' ORDER BY name
```

Comment: Remove second `where`?

Comment: Take a look at the docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Comment: Hi felixRo. This is a very basic question and it looks like you need to do a little self-learning. Take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp which explain with examples how where & and work.

Comment: should I delete this post? It's kind of embarrassing, too simple for posting this here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use only one where with and/or operations.

```
WHERE [condition] AND [condition] OR [condition] AND [condition]
```

You can use this following code

```
SELECT id, name FROM table_name WHERE state=1 AND name LIKE '%ss%' ORDER BY name
```

Comment: now it's simple, it's just second condition of where